# How to get Sceneform 1.16.0 working with Android Studio latest version

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

i followed the sceneform documentation for 1.16.0 and i can not get it to work with my Android build. What am i missing?

I am not able to import assets by right clicking, and Android studio states that it can not resolve the symbol sceneform.

Comment: How are you importing sceneform via gradle and also, I believe you should be using Sceneform 1.17.1 or the latest one managed by the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using sceneform 1.16 try using this open-source version of scene form [sceneform open. source](https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android)